# insert chapters into document

Tags: chapters

I am having trouble inserting chapters into my document. When I use:

```
\chapter{My Chapter}
```

the pdf simply displays 'My Chapter' in normal font, with no "Chapter 1" etc etc.

My document is set out as :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[options]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\let\centering\relax
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{name}{system}{definition}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
```

\chapter{My Chapter}

```
\end{document}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `article` document class does not define `\chapter`...

Comment: Migrate the document at least to the `report` class. Since you seem to miss such basics, I recommend to read some introductory material like the »[Dickimaw LaTeX Books](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/)«.

Comment: TeX would have stopped with an error message saying that \chapter is not defined: You should not ignore the error messages! any pdf that may result after an error is essentially arbitrary as the recovery from errors is designed to get TeX into a stable state to process more input, not designed to produce any particular output.

Comment: don't do `\let\centering\relax`  redefining core latex features can have wide ranging effects, whatever the intended change is here there must be a safer way to do it.